# GWT - Unable to find /path/to/war/WEB-INF/lib/shared?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to use the Google Plugin for eclipse to run a GWT/GAE project as a web application, but I keep running into the error:

```
Unable to find path/to/war/WEB-INF/lib/shared
```

More specifically, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Logging.initializeLogging(Logging.java:35)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:77)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find path/to/war/WEB-INF/lib/shared
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo._getLibs(SdkInfo.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo.getLibsRecursive(SdkInfo.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo.determineSharedLibFiles(SdkInfo.java:302)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo.init(SdkInfo.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo.getSdkRoot(SdkInfo.java:190)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkImplInfo.<clinit>(SdkImplInfo.java:19)
```

I had this application running fine previously, but it's been a while since I've worked on it. The GWT code compiles fine. It's only on attempting to run the code in a development server that this error arises. Looking through my previous commits I don't seem to see a time when WEB-INF/lib/shared ever existed, so either this is some new requirement or shared was just never committed in the past.

[The only "solution"](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8616) I've found online claims that they fixed it by removing appengine-utils-client-1.0.jar and appengine-utils-server-1.0.jar. However, neither of these seem to be in my project, so I don't think this solution will help me.

Any suggestions? Thank you much.

Comment: Any chance it is this bug - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8616

Comment: change your path relative to the `war` folder,ie `WEB-INF/lib/shared`

Comment: @SSR: That's actually the solution I link to in my question and this fix doesn't work for me as I explain above. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Abin: Change which path? WEB-INF/lib/shared doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same trouble, I just ended up creating a new GWT setup and copying in my src files, and WEB-INF files that I specifically created/modified.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem also, after upgrading to GAE 1.8.0.   Removing the appengine-tools-api.jar from the WEB-INF/lib directory solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you - this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using GWTUpload.  The previous posts helped me get on the right track, although I didn't have the jars mentioned in my web-inf/lib.  Finally solved it by adding a Maven exclusion for appengine-tools-sdk.  So my final GWTUpload pom.xml Maven code is:

```
    <!-- GWTUpload  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtupload</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtupload-gae</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- This exclusion got rid of the super hard to track down IllegalArgumentException on startup related to SdkInfo  -->
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```